# call a method on a object list of the same class

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to call a class method of all objects in a list?
Example:

```
    %my_objects contains a list of instances of the same user matlab class
    my_objects(:).my_func(42);
```

The purpose of this is to filter indexes instead of using ":"
Example:

```
    my_objects(1:10).my_func(42);
```

or

```
    my_objects(find(...)).my_func(42);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so if you use `arrayfun()`, `cellfun()` or `structfun()`, depending on what "list" means.

Let's assume it is an array (matrix), you can do

```
arrayfun(@(obj)obj.my_func(42), my_objects)
```

which iterates over `my_objects` and calls `obj.myfunc(42)` for each of the contained objects.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as elegant as you would like , but can you iterate through the list, reference each object in turn, and then perform your operation conditionally via the reference?

```
for iObj = 1:length(my_objects)
   anObj = my_objects(iObj)
   if (predicate(anObj))
      anObj.my_func(42);
   end
end
```